# Show exit button along with continue button on question in docassemble

Tags: python, yaml, docassemble

I'm trying to show **exit button** on every question along with the continue button in **docassemble**. Continue button is generated by default by docassemble but I want to have the exit button too. I'm aware that it's not possible to have more than one directives with a question but I'm wondering if there's a **trick** to do it somehow. I've gone through the docs and didn't find anything that could work to show the exit button.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`action buttons`](https://docassemble.org/docs/questions.html#action%20buttons), but you would need to add it to each `question` in the YAML. There is no feature for adding additional buttons to every screen in an interview.

```
code: |
  exit_button = [{'action': 'https://docassemble.org', 'label': 'Exit', 'icon': 'sign-out-alt', 'color': 'danger'}]
---
mandatory: True
question: |
  Do you like fruit?
yesno: likes_fruit
action buttons:
  code: exit_button
---
mandatory: True
question: |
  Do you like vegetables?
yesno: likes_vegetables
action buttons:
  code: exit_button
---
mandatory: True
question: |
  What is your favorite color?
fields:
  - Color: favorite_color
action buttons:
  code: exit_button
---
mandatory: True
question: Done
action buttons:
  code: exit_button
```

Alternatively, you could create a JavaScript file in the static folder, include it in your interview with `features` -> `javascript`, and in the JavaScript file you could add a [`daPageLoad`](https://docassemble.org/docs/functions.html#js_daPageLoad) listener that adds a button to the button `<div>` (which you can find at `fieldset.da-button-set`).

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution! I implemented your solution for exit button using action buttons. Now I'm want to add a restart button too along with continue and exit buttons. I've tried various methods but I'm unable to implement it properly. Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This will add a restart button:
`exit_button = [{'action': 'https://docassemble.org', 'label': 'Exit', 'icon': 'sign-out-alt', 'color': 'danger'}, {'action': '?reset=1', 'label': 'Restart', 'icon': 'undo', 'color': 'warning'}]`